# Создание листа в Excel по шаблону xlt

Tags: python, excel, шаблоны-документов

Мне нужно добавить в книгу Excel страницу по шаблону temp.xlt, как это можно реализовать на примере этого кода?

```
wb = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = wb.add_sheet("Лист 1")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Страницы поддаются копированию через функцию `deepcopy`. Вот пример полного копирования всех страниц шаблонного файла XLT с возможностью модификации:

```
from copy import deepcopy
from xlrd import open_workbook
from xlutils.copy import copy as copy
from xlwt import Workbook
rb = open_workbook('filename.xlt', formatting_info=True)
wb = copy(rb)
new_book = Workbook()

sheets = []
# Обход всех страниц шаблона
for sheet in wb():
    new_sheet = deepcopy(sheet)

    # Любая нужная модификация страниц
    new_sheet.write(...)
    new_sheet.set_name(...)

    # Добавить страницу в итоговый список
    sheets.append(new_sheet)

 # Добавляем полученные страницы в WorkBook
 new_book._Workbook__worksheets = sheets
```

Этот код легко адаптировать под конкретные любые нужды, например, можно копировать одну страницу несколько раз.

<sub>Основано на [этом ответе из enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14318900/5308802)</sub>